# Algorithm to draw a graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, layout, graph, tree

I have implemented a graph, using an adjacency list.
I have all the info i need for every vertex: depth, number of siblings, pointer to its parent vertex(it can only have one parent), info about its children and so on.

I would like to draw the hierarchy of the graph, preferably left to right.
I am trying to think of an algorithm which will compute the coordinate (x,y) of each vertex.

Regarding the layout total space, I have information about the height and weight of the total layout, and also info about the weight and height of the vertices, but at the moment they can be treated as points.

It was easy to come up with a "formula" that returns the X coordinate: every level we are going deeper in the graph/tree we progress on the X axis.

But i'm confused about how to calculate the Y coordiate for each vertex. And I assume that someone has thougt of this before me. Couldn't find anything useful after looking it up and finding out that it's a well known problem.

Answer (score 0):

Getting X and Y coordinates right for most general cases of graph layout is not an easy task.

You might want to take a look at some open source tools to find out how they do it.

Graphviz has some good algorithms for layout
http://www.graphviz.org/

Antlr is another
http://www.antlr.org/